# How to echo $lang->line ('') instead of $this->lang->line ('') in view

Tags: codeigniter

I need to change my controller so that I can output the language file with in my view with this syntax `echo $lang->line ('')` instead of the CI standard `echo $this->lang->line ('')`. I may not change the code in my view.

View :

```
<div id="back-to-top"><a href="#"><?php echo $lang->line('general_back_to_top'); ?></a></div>
```

Controller :

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->lang->load('general', 'en');
    }

    public function footer()
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/bmain_plain_footer');
    }
```

Comment: *How to echo $lang->line ('') instead of $this->lang->line ('') in view*: what is the reason for going against the documented approach? [Codeigniter Language Class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/language.html) shows you how to use the class. Please point out why you need a different approach. Also if you use internationalization in html links, you'll need to setup routes to follow to the original link (controller/function/parameter)

Comment: I got a task to display the view, and that's how the code was written in view so I need to follow without having to change the code :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve this in the controller, where you are calling your view (assuming it is the function you mentioned in your question), [adding Dynamic Data to the View](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/views.html?#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view):

```
public function footer()
{
   $data['lang']=$this->lang; 
   $this->load->view('templates/bmain_plain_footer', $data);
}
```

Now you can display your data in your view as pretended:

```
echo $this->lang->line('general_back_to_top');
```

*note:* as you are using the internationalization within a link, you should prepare a route for that link so that all language versions point to the same controller.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the idea! I've posted the answer, it looks similar to yours, but there are few additional line.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer for my question! :)

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->lang->load('general', 'en');
    }


    public function footer()
    {
        $data['lang'] = $this->lang;
        $this->load->view('templates/bmain_plain_footer', $data);
    }
```

Comment: `$this->lang->line('lang_item');`in your constructor doesn't do anything